# How to add value to object and remove current value?

Tags: javascript, object

I have data like this :

```
users = [{
    "emp_id": 1,
    "user": {
        "emp_full_name": "Test",
        "emp_email": "test@gmail.com",
        "emp_phone_no": null,
        "preferred_work_type": null
    },
    "hashtag": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "NodeJs",
        "hashtag_group_id": 1
    },
    "difficulty": "HARD"
}, {
    "emp_id": 2,
    "user": {
        "emp_full_name": "test2",
        "emp_email": "test2@gmail.com",
        "emp_phone_no": null,
        "preferred_work_type": null
    },
    "hashtag": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "NodeJs",
        "hashtag_group_id": 1
    },
    "difficulty": "EASY"
}, {
    "emp_id": 1,
    "user": {
        "emp_full_name": "Test",
        "emp_email": "test@gmail.com",
        "emp_phone_no": null,
        "preferred_work_type": null
    },
    "hashtag": {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Javascript",
        "hashtag_group_id": 1
    },
    "difficulty": "HARD"
}]
```

I want to add `hashtag` to same the object that has the same `emp_id`. If `emp_id` has more than one data then the data that has the `emp_id` with the single `hashtag` data should be removed.

So basically this is what I expected:

```
[{
    "emp_id": 1,
    "user": {
        "emp_full_name": "Test",
        "emp_email": "test@gmail.com",
        "emp_phone_no": null,
        "preferred_work_type": null
    },
    "hashtag": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "NodeJs",
        "hashtag_group_id": 1
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Javascript",
        "hashtag_group_id": 1
    }],
    "difficulty": "HARD"
}, {
    "emp_id": 2,
    "user": {
        "emp_full_name": "test2",
        "emp_email": "test2@gmail.com",
        "emp_phone_no": null,
        "preferred_work_type": null
    },
    "hashtag": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "NodeJs",
        "hashtag_group_id": 1
    },
    "difficulty": "EASY"
}]
```

How to transform the data like that?

I have no idea how to solve that, I tried using `filter()`, and `map()` with some validation condition, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` with `.findIndex()`. Try this

```js
let users = '[{"emp_id": 1, "user": {"emp_full_name": "Test", "emp_email": "test@gmail.com", "emp_phone_no": null, "preferred_work_type": null }, "hashtag": {"id": 1, "name": "NodeJs", "hashtag_group_id": 1 }, "difficulty": "HARD"}, {"emp_id": 2, "user": {"emp_full_name": "test2", "emp_email": "test2@gmail.com", "emp_phone_no": null, "preferred_work_type": null }, "hashtag": {"id": 1, "name": "NodeJs", "hashtag_group_id": 1 }, "difficulty": "EASY"}, {"emp_id": 1, "user": {"emp_full_name": "Test", "emp_email": "test@gmail.com", "emp_phone_no": null, "preferred_work_type": null }, "hashtag": {"id": 4, "name": "Javascript", "hashtag_group_id": 1 }, "difficulty": "HARD"} ]';
users = JSON.parse(users)

users = users.reduce((arr, o) => {
    let idx = arr.findIndex(({emp_id}) => emp_id === o.emp_id);
    if( idx !== -1 ) arr[idx].hashtag = [].concat(arr[idx].hashtag, o.hashtag)
    else arr.push(o)

    return arr;
}, []);

console.log(users)
```

Comment: i was using your code but still have problem that i mention in other answer comment

Comment: @user18605090 it seems you response is a JSON string. You have to convert it to an array using `JSON.parse()`. I've updated my answer kindly check it out

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Map keyed by `emp_id` and collect the users by that key. When there is already an entry, extend the `hashtag` using `[].concat`. This will create an array if it wasn't an array yet.

```js
const users = [{"emp_id": 1,"user": {"emp_full_name": "Test","emp_email": "test@gmail.com","emp_phone_no": null,"preferred_work_type": null},"hashtag": {"id": 1,"name": "NodeJs","hashtag_group_id": 1},"difficulty": "HARD"},{"emp_id": 2,"user": {"emp_full_name": "test2","emp_email": "test2@gmail.com","emp_phone_no": null,"preferred_work_type": null},"hashtag": {"id": 1,"name": "NodeJs","hashtag_group_id": 1},"difficulty": "EASY"},{"emp_id": 1,"user": {"emp_full_name": "Test","emp_email": "test@gmail.com","emp_phone_no": null,"preferred_work_type": null},"hashtag": {"id": 4,"name": "Javascript","hashtag_group_id": 1},"difficulty": "HARD"}];

const map = new Map;
for (const user of users) {
    const match = map.get(user.emp_id);
    if (match) match.hashtag = [].concat(match.hashtag, user.hashtag);
    else map.set(user.emp_id, {...user});
}
const result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I already using your code but dont know why it's not working in mine. I already double checked the code

Comment: If you can post your code in a fiddle (like on jsfiddle.net), I could have a look at it. Please explain what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: I made a little update to avoid that the original objects are mutated.

Comment: was check in jsfiddle.net, it's work there. it's weird in my local doesn't work. let me check again

Comment: the data was correct when i try console.log(result[0].hashtag) it show the added hashtag, but when i return to response, res.status(200).json(result). it's showing 2 ids, but without the hashtag that already concat. What's the problem with that ?

Comment: actually the ```users``` was the result from querying database with sequelize

Comment: That is a different problem, and means your array is changing *after* it was retrieved. `console.log` is lazy and if you expand an array in the console, it will show data that was added *after* the `console.log` executed. See [Is Chrome’s JavaScript console lazy about evaluating objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects). For you it means you are triggering the conversion too soon, and need to await that later modification, which may happen asynchronously. But all this is unrelated to your question here.